# ¿Cómo utilizo 'zero_division'?

Tags: python

Estoy ejecutando este código:

```py
target_names = ['stroke{0}'.format(i) for i in DF2['stroke'].unique() except] 
print(classification_report(y_test, pred_rf_2, target_names=target_names))
```

pero al ejecutarlo me aparece este mensaje:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1344: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.  
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1344: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use \`zero_division\` parameter to control this behavior.  
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

¿Cómo puedo realizar el cálculo?

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1344: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use \`zero_division\` parameter to control this behavior.  
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

Comment: El mensaje dice "Use zero_division parameter to control this behavior." = "Usa el parámetro zero_division para controlar este comportamiento". ¿Intentaste lo que dice el mensaje? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: ¿Qué cálculo exactamente? Pregunto porque el cálculo si que se está realizando. El warning dice básicamente que hay etiquetas para las que no hay datos, pero es eso, una advertencia, no un error.